# GORM, giving names for the columns of a joinTable with a composite id

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Working with Grails 1.3.7, I've to deal with a legacy DB. I've a domain object ''Cake'' which have it's own collection of embedded ''Ingredients'', in a join table.

Ingredient.groovy

```
class Ingredient {
  String name
  IngredientCategory category

  mapping {
    table "foo_ingredient"
    version false
    id composite:['name', 'category']
    columns {
      word     column:"the_name"
     category column:"lol_category_id"
    }
  }
```

}

Cake.groovy

```
class Cake {
  String name

  static hasMany = [ ingredients : Ingredient ]

  static mapping = {
    table "foo_cake"
    version false
    columns {
      id   column:"id"
      name column:"the_name"
    }

    ingredients joinTable: [
      name : "foo_cake_ingredient",
      key  : "cake_id"
    ]
  }
}
```

Problem is, Grails expect that the table ''foo_cake_ingredient'' to have two columns ''ingredient_name'' and ''ingredient_category_id''. I would like to specify manually those column names and not let Grails (wrongly) guess those. I can't figure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I showed how to do this here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Composite-foreign-key-td3046351.html#a3046436

Comment: Sadly, it does not work for me :( It seems that a set of embedded objects, can not express that in GORM.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a hibernate xml mapping for the two tables in this relationship.

Have you read http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2006/06/20/hoisting-grails-to-your-legacy-db/ ?